# I have a error when my program run (Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'userInput' was corrupted.)

Tags: c++, error-handling, runtime-error, runtime

I'm new here so sorry if I have post on the wrong section.

When I run my program I get the error (Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'userInput' was corrupted.) I don't know what I have make for this to run. (sorry for my English I'm french). If you could help me on that it will be appreciate. I have try to run it trough a lot of debugger (Visual studio, gdb, gdb online, ..) but I still cannot found why. If you could review my code too. Like big mistake that you found it will be appreciate. Thanks :)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

// START FUNCTION DECLARATION 

void setupGame(int gameBoard[4][19]);
void showGrid(int gameBoard[4][19]);
void calulateGame(std::string userInput);

// END FUNCTION DECLARATION 

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    // Basic game variable
    std::string userInput = "";
    bool bGameLoop = true;
    int gameBoard[4][19];

    // Setup the game
    setupGame(gameBoard);

    do {
        // Reloading the scene
        //system("clear");

        // Show/Update the game grid
        showGrid(gameBoard);

        // Wait for user input
        /*userInput = "";
        std::cin >> userInput;
        if (userInput != "w" || userInput != "a" ||
        userInput != "s" || userInput != "d")
        {
            std::cout << "Please use [W][A][S][D] to move <3";
        }*/

    } while (bGameLoop);

    return 0;
}


// START FUNCTION  

/**
* Calculate all in the game (if user died, cannot go, win, etc)
* @param userInput The last input
*/
/*void calulateGame(std::string userInput) {


}*/

/**
* Show the grid.
*/
void showGrid(int gameBoard[4][19]) {

    //# -------------------- #                                              
    //|O.................... |                                           
    //# -------------------- # 

    // Show top bar
    std::cout << "DUNGEON CRAWL V1\n\n";

    std::cout << "#--------------------#\n";
    std::string cToOut;
    for (int y = 0; y <= 4; y++) {
        std::cout << "|";
        for (int x = 0; x <= 19; x++) {
            switch (gameBoard[y][x]) {
                case 0:
                    cToOut = " ";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    cToOut = "@";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    cToOut = "X";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    cToOut = "O";
                    break;
                default:
                    cToOut = " ";
                    break;
                };

            std::cout << cToOut;
        }
        std::cout << "|\n";
    }

    std::cout << "#--------------------#\n";
}

/**
* Create the game array and setup trap and the player.
*/
void setupGame(int gameBoard[4][19]) {
    // 0 = empty data
    // 1 = player 
    // 2 = exit
    // 3 = trap

    // Populate array with zero
    for (int y = 0; y <= 4; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x <= 19; x++) {
            gameBoard[y][x] = 0;
        }
    }

    // Setup player & exit
    gameBoard[0][0] = 1;
    gameBoard[4][19] = 2;

    // Setup random trap 
    int trapX, trapY;
    bool bAlreadyUse = false;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int t = 1; t <= 5; t++) {
        do {
            trapX = rand() % 19;
            trapY = rand() % 4;

            if (gameBoard[trapY][trapX] == 3) {
                bAlreadyUse = true;
            }
            else {
                bAlreadyUse = false;
            }

            // Dont use spawn or end pos
        } while ((trapX == 0 && trapY == 0) || (trapX == 19 && trapY == 4)
            || bAlreadyUse);

        gameBoard[trapY][trapX] = 3;
    }
}

// END FUNCTION
```

I have forgot to mention that I'm new in c++. And this is a game to try :)

Comment: `for (int y = 0; y <= 4; y++) {` etal... You are going past the end of the array. Valid indexes for `some_array[4]` are `0,1,2,3`. This loop uses indexes `0,1,2,3,4`. Use `for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++) {`

Comment: `srand(time(NULL));` is a terrible way to seed a bad random generator. You should look into the new facilities from the `<random>` header. Also, your use of modulo (like in `rand() % 19`) is introducing bias - you really ought to be using a `std::uniform_int_distribution` instead.

Comment: Thanks. Really appreciate :) I will more look into std::uniform_int_distribution !

Comment: Your functions that try to take multi dimensional arrays as arguments (like `setupGame`) *actually* end up taking arrays decayed to pointers. Suggest you make them take `std::array` or `std::vector` instead.